# progress-bar it's not working in chrome when upload file

Tags: javascript, jquery, progress-bar

i use file progress-bar to upload file. this progress-bar is working in Firefox but it's not working in chrome when i was uploading file.
in chrome fileProgress function it's not happen on server but it's working in local.

```
$("#upload-file").change(function () {
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', this.files[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url: serverUrl,
            data: formData,
            type: 'POST',
            headers: { 'ApiKey': checkCookie() },
            xhr: function () {
                //var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                var myXhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                if (myXhr.upload) {
                    myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',fileProgress, false); 
                }
                return myXhr;
            },
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('Success File Upload');
            }
        });
    }
});

function fileProgress(e) {
    if (e.lengthComputable) {
        var max = e.total;
        var current = e.loaded;
        var Percentage = (current * 100) / max;
        $("#upload-file-progress").css("width", Percentage + "%");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your variable `Percentage` is not defined. Write `var Percentage = ...`

Comment: [`.total`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ProgressEvent/total) is not available in Chrome EDIT: also [`.loaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ProgressEvent/loaded)

Comment: What should I do VLAZ?

Comment: @HamidRezaBehzadi sorry, I don't know. I just looked up the documentation. I don't know what the proper way to do this in Chrome is.

Comment: @MauriceNino in chrome fileProgress function it's not happen on server but it's working in local.

Comment: @VLAZ in chrome fileProgress function it's not happen on server but it's working in local.